# Getting error Expected unqualified-id before '{' token c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting this error on this program. I have no idea where the issue is. I am trying for a simple program but no luck. Check my program for the issue. Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    void computeUserLevel (char *);
    main()
    {
        char Y[4];
        for(i=0; i<=4; i++)
        {
            cout<<"arrays and pointers are same:";
             cin>> Y[0];
             cout<<"switch is a loop: ";
             cin>> Y[1];
             cout<<"pointers store memory addresses  : ";
             cin>>Y[2];
        }
        computeUserLevel(Y);
        return 0;

    }
    void computeUserLevel (char *ptr)
    {
        if (*ptr == 'f' && *(ptr+1) == 'f' && *(ptr+2) == 't')
        {
            cout<<"your level is Advance";
        }
        else if (*ptr == 't' && *(ptr+1) == 'f' && *(ptr+2) == 't')
        {
            cout<<"your level is Intermediate";
        }
        else
            cout<< "your level is Beginner";
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea where the error is. Please tell us/show us on which line the eror is reported.

Comment: `main` needs a return type, just like other functions - so `int main()`.

Comment: This is not C...

Comment: Where is you main method? It should be int main(). Plus the variable i in for-loop should be declared before you use it.

Comment: I have already tried `int main()` but still same problem

Comment: Your last version of edited code works fine, voting to close as typo that has been resolved.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do and what is the error you face ?

Comment: But on my editor, it still shows error. I am using DevC++ editor

Comment: Copy-paste the exact, full error message to the question. There is a line number in the error message, show on the code which line throws the error.

Comment: Also make sure that the problem is with the code and not with the editor – try to compile the code *outside* the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry point of the program `main` needs a return type to be mentioned, i.e `int main()`.

Also, you need to mention the type of `i` in the for-loop( see below )

`for( int i = 0; i <4; i++ )`

Comment: i tried with that but no luck

Comment: @shafeequrrehman what have you tried? did you make both changes?

Comment: @rustyx Check my edited question. I already tried with that but no success.

Comment: The code compiles fine with the changes suggested. If you have some other problem, kindly be clearer with it.